# Perform Function After Element Is Revealed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a website where a div tag reveals itself after enough products are selected. What I'm trying to do is add an ID to this div tag after it's revealed using javascript.

**This is the tag that's revealed:**

```
<div class="discount-summary"></div>
```

**This is the javascript I've created:**

```
$(".discount-summary").load($(this),function(){
   addDiscount();
});

function addDiscount() {
            $('.discount-summary').attr('id','discountbox');
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be working.

Comment: `$(this).attr("href")` - It looks like this is trying to load a URL, but you don't show us the href attribute. Are you sure this is getting set? Add some console.logs. Also check the network tab of Chrome's inspector to make sure the network request is completing and not erroing.

Comment: @AndyRay my mistake that should not have been in there. I've updated it.

Comment: Check my answer. Happy coding :)

Comment: Is there a class or an id or attribute you're using to reveal the element?

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation for load.

Comment: What is the value of `$(this)` ? Make sure you console.log that and get used to debugging your own code. You should also get in the habit of reading documentation and verify the methods you're using do what you expect, aka make sure  you read https://api.jquery.com/load/ and double check that you mean to pass a URL string to the load function, not a jQuery collection like you're passing now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Updated**

Try:

```
<div class="discount-summary">Just a test</div>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setInterval(addDiscount, 1000)
});

function addDiscount() {
    $('.discount-summary').attr('id','discountbox');
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/rashedrahat/pen/NWdwaGV)

Comment: The problem with this code is that the div with the class discount summary is already revealed. On my site, it is not revealed on load, but after a couple of products are selected in a shop.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Are you looking for this? Let me know.

Comment: @RashedRahat please don't post comments as answers. This doesn't seem related to the question

Comment: @RashedRahat That's it! Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome :) My pleasure. Please upvote the answer. This will boost my motivation @FeliciaSantos :)